# Django REST, sudden 403 error in ajax call

Tags: ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I have a basic view

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def test(request):
    id = request.POST.get("id")    
    response = {}
    try:
        obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=id)
        response['can'] = False
    except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
        response['can'] = True
    return Response(response)
```

In urls

```
url(r'^test', test),
```

And simple call in template:

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        data : {id:id},
        url  : "/test/",
        success: function(data) {
            if(data['can']){
                $("#Test").show();
            } else{
                $("#Test").hide();
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

And it has worked recently. But today, when I've tested this app I get error:

```
[22/Feb/2016 15:09:02] "POST /test/ HTTP/1.1" 403 58
```

which means "Forbidden access". I have no idea what's going on. Maybe you can help with that.

**EDIT**
I've just noticed that it happens on firefox browser. On ubuntu's "browser" and google chrome I don't have this 403 error.

**EDIT 2** Oh, when I run firefox as private/incognito window I don't have this 403 error. I get this error only when I use 'normal' firefox.

Answer (score 1):

***Possible issue:*** It could be the previous user session is still in the browser cookie. try clearing the cookie of your firefox browser.

On the next try, you may encounter the issue again, so then you trace why certain user are not given permission.

Answer (score 1):

There is no users or any permissions. This is app for 'not-login' users.

I've just added csrf protecion befor ajax call. (from django docs)

```
function getCookie(name) {
var cookieValue = null;
if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
            break;
        }
    }
}
return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

And it's work. Do I think right? This error was caused by a lack of csrf protection?